# Can't resolve the promise

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to make a get request but somehow I can't log the promise from backend. Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

```
  makeLoginCall(_username: string, _password: string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('xxx').subscribe(data => {      
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }

  login() {
    this.userService.makeLoginCall(this.formLogin.value.username, this.formLogin.value.password)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }, 
    (response) => {
      if (response.status < 500) {
        console.warn('Login failed!');
      } else {
        console.error('Internal Server Error');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Err, you never call neither resolve() nor reject().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resolve the `Promise` when you receive a response, so that the underlying `.then` function will get call as soon it gets resolved.

**Code**

```
makeLoginCall(_username: string, _password: string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('xxx').subscribe(data => {   
          resolve(data); //resolve promise here
      });
    });
    return promise;
}
```